# Problemas com wxWidgets

Tags: c, c++

estou fazendo um projeto utilizando o wxWidgets, e quand compilo aparece a mensagem: error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files.
Estou utilizando o codeblocks no ubuntu e não sei o que fazer com este erro.

Comment: Por exemplo ao compilar `cc  -c  a.c b.c` vai criar `a.o` e um `b.o` . Se forçarmos uma saída `cc -o aaa -c a.c b.c` o compilador dá erro do género do que obtens.

Comment: E como eu posso configurar isso no codeblocks?